# I have existing SDKs and I wanted to use that SDK in the react native app

Tags: react-native

Actually, I have existing SDKs and I wanted to use that SDK in the react native app.

For android

1. I tried adding the jar file into the libs folder of /android/app/libs
2. Added dependencies into file /android/app/build.gradle

> *implementation fileTree(include: [‘*.jar’], dir: ‘libs’)*

But I did not get how can I use these jar files in my ts file. How can I create the object and call the methods?

The main concern is how can I use the external java libraries in my react native app?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write native modules to do your required things in JAVA then bridge it to react native. Check [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro) link for reference